# SignalR throws error in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, websocket, signalr

SignalR throws this error in IE10:

```
SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 500, Internal Server Error
```

In Chrome everything is running as expected.
The code that i use:

```
<!--Reference the SignalR library.-->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js")"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script-->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            chat.on('broadcastMessage', function (userId, conversationId, message) {
                NewMessages();
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
</script>
```

And this is the hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string userId,string conversationId, string message)
        {
            //Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(userId, conversationId,message);
        }
    }
```

The server method "Send" get's called correctly but the client side "broadcastMessage" does't.
I did some reading and SignalR is supported in IE10. Does someone have an idea on why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
 chat.client.broadcastMessage = function(userId, conversationId, message)
{
 NewMessages();
}
```